# What is the easiest way to remove the background from this image in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I downloaded these ribbons from freepik[image]

and I want to remove the ribbons from the background. What is the easiest way to do this in illustrator?

It doesn't seem to be a vector because it is one solid image, here are the layers.[image]

Comment: A lot of this will depend on the structure of the vector file.  If they are all contained within clipping masks, then your job will be slightly more work.  If they are each individual groups on top of a red background, then it's really quite simple.  You just need to select the red rectangle and delete it.  If they are in fact in clipping masks, then you'll have to dig through, until you find the red background and delete it.  Can you show me a screen shot of your layers palette?

Comment: If it's vector, click and hit the delete key? Is this a trick question?

Comment: Based on the layer's panel, in **Illustrator** it would be *easiest to redraw* things. Use Photoshop to remove the background, since it appears to be a raster image.

Comment: Why did you not just use the .ai file you downloaded? It was vector. Change the background color and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

From Here: http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/paper-ribbons-vector-set_724790.htm
Download the pack.

Open the .AI file.

Use the white arrow tool to select the background box, hit Delete.

[image]

You might have to delete or redraw some of the shadow elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would download the file again because i do have all the layers, freepik vector always have a masklayer too so remember to: right click, Release clippling mask, the ctrl+a (select all) right-click: Un-group

And if that doesn work because it has to many groups and you dont have time to un-group every object the select the white arrow and click the Red Background, go to select - Same - Fill color (All red vectors should be selected at this point) and hit delete.

At first all those shadows without a BG are going to be weird if you want them i would put another background if you dont want them then ungroup every ribbon you want and delete the shadows.

:)